# Structuring Azure API Headers for use in PowerShell query

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-storage

I am trying to write some PowerShell code to interact with the storage API in Azure Commercial and am having some challenges getting the headers structure correct.

Below is the code I am using to get a token for my Service Principal:

```
# Get token for Azure Resource Manager API
$Body = @{
    'resource'      = $storageResourceID
    'client_id'     = $tf_sp_appid
    'grant_type'    = 'client_credentials'
    'client_secret' = $terraform_sp_secret
}

$params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Headers     = @{'accept' = 'application/json'}
    Body        = $Body
    Method      = 'Post'
    URI         = $TokenEndpoint
}

# Get token
$token = Invoke-RestMethod @params
```

When I run the code below to get a list of all of the containers in a storage account, it throws the an error about an Invalid Header Value:

```
$getDate = ((get-date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('R')
$RestAPIParams = @{
    Uri    = "https://$storageAcctName.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list"
    Method = "Get"
    Verbose = $true
    Headers = @{
        'authorization' = "Bearer $($token.access_token)"
        'x-ms-date' = "$getDate"
        'x-ms-version' = "2017-10-01"
        }
    }
$result = (Invoke-RestMethod @RestAPIParams).value
```

[image]

Comment: You're specifying `2017-10-01` for `x-ms-version` header but there's no REST API version matching that. Please see the list of available REST API versions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/previous-azure-storage-service-versions. Can you try your request with `2018-03-28` for `x-ms-version`?

Comment: @GauravMantri you were correct on the API version. That is one of the biggest challenges for me is determining the versions on all of the different APIs. It is no longer erroring out for me but it does not return anything where I thought it should be returning a list of the containers in that specified storage account. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list containers in a storage account with the access token, you could refer to the command below, I use a v1 AD App, it works fine on my side.

```
# Get token for Azure Resource Manager API
$Body = @{
    'resource'      = 'https://management.azure.com/'
    'client_id'     = '<your client id>'
    'grant_type'    = 'client_credentials'
    'client_secret' = "<your client secret>"
}

$params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Headers     = @{'accept' = 'application/json'}
    Body        = $Body
    Method      = 'Post'
    URI         = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant id>/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0'
}

# Get token
$token = Invoke-RestMethod @params

$RestAPIParams = @{
    Uri    = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage account name>/blobServices/default/containers?api-version=2018-03-01-preview"
    Method = "Get"
    Verbose = $true
    Headers = @{
        'authorization' = "Bearer $($token.access_token)"
        }
    }
$result = (Invoke-RestMethod @RestAPIParams).value
```

**Test result**:

[image]

Comment: This is all confusing to me. There seems to be many different ways to do the same task. Ultimately...I want to be able to use the API to copy files into a blob container. This article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json gives you detail on assigning permission to a Service Principal for the Azure Storage API and how to obtain a token but when I then use that token to perform operations in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2, I get nothing back.

Comment: @phydeauxman Are you insist on using the [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2)? I think my solution will work fine. If you want to copy files into a container, where are the files? BTW, why not login with a service principal and use the [`Get-AzureRmStorageContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.storage/get-azurermstoragecontainer?view=azurermps-6.13.0) powershell command, it is convenient.

Comment: we don't have access to the AzureRm module on the machines we are working with...long story. I am trying to understand the "why" on the different APIs.

Comment: @phydeauxman If you catch the request of the `Get-AzureRmStorageContainer` command, you will get the api I used. So, if you want to do other operations, just use the same way. Theoretically speaking, the powershell command will essentially call the same api with that in the official doc, but not know why isn't.

Comment: @phydeauxman Anyway, I think my solution can solve the issue of your post, could you accept it as the answer?

Comment: have not been able to get back to that issue. Will give it a try later in the week and let you know how it goes